# Validate fields on multiple Fragments hosted by a ViewPager

Tags: android, validation, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My app works with a long form which I decided to divide in multiple `Fragments` in a `ViewPager`. When you press the "save" option, the validation process starts.

Basically the validation is that some `EditTexts` are not empty. I'm looping through all `Fragments` in the `ViewPager` check if all fields has valid values.

```
// Inside Fragment
public boolean areFieldsValid() {
    return !mEditText.getText().toString().isEmpty()
}

public void showErrors() {
    mEditText.setError("cannot be blank");
}
```

If a field inside a `Fragment` is not valid, then `viewPager.setCurrentItem(position, true);` and `fragment.showErrors()` are called to go to that `Fragment` and show the user the error.

The problem comes when `onCreateView()` hasn't been called on the `Fragment` that has the error.

This happens either because you haven't navigated to that `Fragment` yet (supposing the user's on `fragment1`, error is on `fragment7` and the user pressed "save" while on `fragment1`)  or because the user rotated the device and all views are destroyed on every `Fragment`.

This problem/issue is not only that `mEditText` would be **null**, but also that the `Fragment` saved its state, so it might not even been blank. In other words, the following code is not an option, because even if the pointer is null, it might not be empty.

```
// Inside Fragment
public boolean areFieldsValid() {
    return mEditText != null && !mEditText.getText().toString()isEmpty();
}
```

At this point I'm wondering if my architecture is wrong. I decided to go with `ViewPager` cause the form is **really** long, and I've been passing data from `Fragment` to `Activity` through callbacks.

Given the above settings, how can I validate fields **and** show the user which field is the one with the error?

Comment: can you post some code how you validate on save button click?

Comment: nothing fancy, just loop through a list of `Fragments` and call `areFieldsValid()`  and if `false`, also call `viewPager.setCurrentItem(thatFragmentPosition)` and then `showErrors()`

Comment: and you are doing is the last fragment of all?

Comment: where is your save button? on which fragment?

Comment: in the `ActionBar`, on the host `Activity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up validating each `Fragment` **before** moving to the next one.

**Reason:**
The initial idea was to validate on save, and if there was an `Fragment` with invalid data, move to that fragment and show the errors. But since there is no way to determine the state of `Views` inside a `Fragment` if it is not visible, you cannot validate input.

Comment: Where do you put the validation code? Do you validate when the user swipes to the next fragment?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just assume that UI components will be there anytime you want. That fragment might be gone, killed or worse, destroyed without saving it's instance state.

What I offer is to save data on database and check if everything is set on save button click event. This can be done using ContentProviders and SQLiteDatabase. As Virgil Said in [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xHXn3Kg2IQE) "Persist more, persist often."

Comment: The form is really long because it saves about 5 entities to the database. All those entities are related to each other through "foreign" keys (SQLite doesn't support them, so they are manually managed). I don't wanna run a manual delete-cascade each time the user decides to cancel the entry.

Comment: I smell too much data integrity problems. Also if you are targeting api level 8 (Froyo, 2.2) You have foreign keys.

Comment: Foreign keys are not the problem. Either way my whole architecture using a ViewPager as a host for a multi-page form is wrong, or there is a way to validate this depending on each view's state saved by each fragment.

Comment: Ok, let's make this clear. UI components like Fragments and Views should only be responsible for showing some data, and sending messages to some other layers on your application to change data. By not dividing responsibility you are generating nightmares for future versions. If you're not planning to use your application on a broader scale, or planning to rip off your customer quick and dirty ways are always fine, but if you are planning to create great applications with happy users you should minimize maintenance time. Android applications are subject to Software Engineering too, remember. =)

Comment: yeah, that's what i want. I have divided all responsabilities, even validation is also done on data layer. Now i'm just wanting to add validation on UI layer (for user experience).  Maybe what I should do is prevent the swipe behavior if a field is incorrect, and save action will only be on the last fragment?

Comment: Instead you can persist data on a temporary table on fling event. Then check that table on data layer for validation on save button click. Or you can validate before the fling and persist and if valid. You should persist on every scenario :D

Comment: What you propose sounds pretty nice, the thing is I'm already persisting data using an Entity class in the Host Activity. I think I'll go by validating each fragment before moving on to the next one

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a similar thing, but my approach is to go fragment by fragment. Hope this helps.

I add an interface,

```
public interface AddActionInterface {
    public void onAddButtonClicked(); 
}
```

I created a base fragment which implements this interface as,

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment implements AddActionInterface {

  @Override
  public void onAddButtonClicked() {
    if (isAdded() && isVisible()) {
        executeAction();
    }
  }

  protected abstract void executeAction();

}
```

Then we will call our Interface object like this in the activity. Create a List like below,

```
List<AddActionInterface> listeners = new ArrayList<AddActionInterface>();
```

and add your fragment to the list inside the view pager as,

```
listeners.add(fragment);
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, tag).commit();
```

Simply call the below in the onOptionsItemSelected method.

```
if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add) {          
for (AddActionInterface listener : listeners) {             
   listener.onAddButtonClicked();
}
}
```

What the above method does is calls the onAddButtonClicked() method which is implemented in the BaseFragment.

Trick here is that every time the button in the action bar is clicked it will pass the control to the BaseFragment which checks if the current fragment is still attached then will call the `executeAction()` method of the respective fragment which being abstract every fragment can have their own implementation.

So say for FragmentA you will simply have to extend it from BaseFragment and override executeAction() method. You can write fragment specific implementations.

This process is called dependency inversion principle. See if you can put all these pieces in right place else let me know. :) Wow this is huge. :)

Answer (score 0):

On the viewpager class:

```
  public  void validate() {
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
      Fragment fragment = mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i);
      if(!(fragment instanceof Validetable)) {
        return;
       }
       Validetable validetable = (Validetable) mSectionsPagerAdapter.getItem(i);
       Fragment invalidFragment = validetable.validate();
       if (invalidFragment == null) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "valido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       else {
     mViewPager.setCurrentItem(i);
         break;
       }
}

On each fragment you do:
```

public static boolean isValid = true;

```
@Override
public Fragment validate() {
  if ( StringUtils.isBlank(ColetaLocal.getInstance().getNivel())) {
    isValid = false;
    return this; 
  }
  isValid = true;
  return null;
}


@Override
public void onResume () {
    super.onResume();
    treatErrorsShowing();
}

private void treatErrorsShowing() {
    if (!isValid) {
        showErrors();
    }
    else {
        clearErrors();
    }
}
```

Comment: ColetaLocal is the model, a singleton where i am holding the data.

Comment: On the fragment another interface implemented..:  @Override
 public void textChanged() {
  ColetaLocal.getInstance().setNivel(textView.getText()
    .toString());
  validateAndTreatErrors();
  
 }